# Entry written with onmouseover

Tags: javascript, jquery, onmouseover, onmouseout

I want to insert a written Text inside a block at onmouseover.

My HTML source code is :

```
    <li id="v4">
      <div class="cl">
        <div>
          <span class="m">Text</span>
      <span class="count"></span>
      <span class="pr">
         <span class="p">0%</span>
      </span>
          <!-- insert written : <span class="c1">Vote</span> -->
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
```

To insert the text in place of the comment, I wrote this Javascript code :

```
                    document.getElementById("v4").onmouseover = addSpan;            
        document.getElementById("v4").onmouseout =removeSpan;

        function addSpan(id)
        {           

            var li=document.getElementById(this.getAttribute("id"));            
            var divcell=li.firstChild;  

            var divelem=divcell.firstChild; 
            var span=document.createElement("span");
            span.setAttribute("class","c1");

            var testo=document.createTextNode("Vote");
            span.appendChild(testo);

            divelem.appendChild(span);                              
            span.style.display = 'block';

        }           
        function removeSpan(id)
        {               

            var li=document.getElementById(this.getAttribute("id"));            
            var divcell=li.firstChild;  

            var divelem=divcell.firstChild;//div            
            var span = divelem.lastChild;
            span.style.display='none';              
            divelem.removeChild(divelem.lastChild);     


        }
```

The problem is that the written link.
How can solve this problem? Is my code correct?

[Edit]: i added css for you to see what happens [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bHdbr/2/).
I used the code jquery of @Konstantin D-Infragistics but there is the same problem that is: when the mouse passes over the written "Text to add" it blink. 
I hope that the question is now clearer

Comment: Please consider adding a working example on http://jsfiddle.net/ (or similar)

Comment: Please look into jQuery. It makes your life easier, and the sooner you start with it, the sooner you will love writing JS. Pure JS bugs are a lot rarer using jQuery.

Comment: Your function expects `id` as a parameter but you don't seem to be passing anything into the function.

Comment: What exactly is the problem with (which?) link?

Comment: The code works, but the writing is not fixed but flashes

Comment: @Tanuzzo88 I'm not sure what you mean by flashing here is a working js fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/MTYxz/. The reason for the flitting (flashing) that I can presume is because you have attached the functionality to the `onmouseover` and `onmouseout` event means that if you hover over the element and then quickly move the mouse the dynamically added span tag will flash up and disappear

Comment: Why do you need that all code? You can put your link into that place on server and use css to show it.

Comment: I edited the post adding the css, it is in Edit

Answer (score 1):

Possible solution of your problem is here...Hope this could help you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">

<style type="text/css">
.hide {
    display:none;
 }
.show {
    display:block;
 }   
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
   var el;
window.onload=function() {
   el=document.getElementById('status');
   el.onmouseover=function() {
   changeText('hide','show')
 }
   el.onmouseout=function() {
   changeText('show','hide');
  }
 }
function changeText(cl1,cl2) {
   document.getElementById('span1').className=cl1;
   document.getElementById('span2').className=cl2;
}
</script>

</head>
<body>

<p id="status">
<span id="span1">[Closed]</span>
<span id="span2" class="hide"><a id="link" href="index.php">Open</a></span>
</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider making your life easier by using jQuery. If you add jQuery then you can achieve the functionality you would like the following way:

```
$('#v4').bind({
   'mouseover': function (event) {
       $('<span class="c4">Text to add</span>').appendTo($(this).find('div div'));
   },
   'mouseout': function (event) {
       $('.c4').remove();
   },
});
```

Here it is in [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bHdbr/).

Comment: I used your code, but there is same problem : [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bHdbr/2/) , when the mouse passes over the written "Text to add" it blink.